# php - sort an array by key to match another array's order by key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays, both have the same keys (different values) however array #2 is in a different order. I want to be able to resort the second array so it is in the same order as the first array.

Is there a function that can quickly do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can't think of any off the top of my head, but if the keys are the same across both arrays then why not just loop over the first one and use its key order to create a new array using the the values from the 2nd one?

```
$arr1 = array(
    'a' => '42', 
    'b' => '551',
    'c' => '512',
    'd' => 'gge',
) ;


$arr2 = array(
    'd' => 'ordered',
    'b' => 'is',
    'c' => 'now',
    'a' => 'this', 
) ;

$arr2ordered = array() ;

foreach (array_keys($arr1) as $key) {
    $arr2ordered[$key] = $arr2[$key] ;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`array_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php)

```
$arr1 = [
    'x' => '42', 
    'y' => '551',
    'a' => '512',
    'b' => 'gge',
];


$arr2 = [
    'a' => 'ordered',
    'x' => 'this',
    'y' => 'is',
    'b' => 'now',
];

$arr2 = array_replace($arr1, $arr2);
```

`$arr2` is now

```
[
    'x' => this,
    'y' => is,
    'a' => ordered,
    'b' => now,

]
```

Comment: I upvoted it, but, maybe, for nothing, because result is the following: `array (
  'd' => 'ordered',
  'b' => 'is',
  'c' => 'now',
  'a' => 'this',
)`

Comment: Yes, the right is `array_multisort(array_keys($arr1), SORT_DESC, SORT_STRING, $arr2);`

Comment: No again! Result is `array ( 'a' => 'this', 'c' => 'now', 'b' => 'is', 'd' => 'ordered', )`! I think, you don't test your answers.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, will be better to use `array_replace`, now it is right, i hope.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(array_keys($array1) as $key)
{
  $tempArray[$key] = $array2[$key];
}
$array2 = $tempArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure if this is what your after. anyways as long as the the array remains the same size, than this should work for you.

```
$gamey = array ("wow" => "World of Warcraft", "gw2" => "Guild Wars2", "wiz101" => "Wizard 101");
$gamex = array ("gw2" => "best game", "wiz101" => "WTF?", "wow" => "World greatest");


function match_arrayKeys ($x, $y)
{
    $keys    = array_keys ($x);
    $values  = array_values ($y);

    for ($x = 0; $x < count ($keys); $x++)
    {
        $newarray [$keys[$x]] = $y[$keys[$x]];
    }
    return $newarray;
}

print_r (match_arrayKeys ($gamey, $gamex));
```

Output

```
[wow] => World greatest
[gw2] => best game
[wiz101] => WTF?
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this
**CODE**

```
$fruits = array("d"=>"lemon", "a"=>"orange", "b"=>"banana", "c"=>"apple");
ksort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a = orange
b = banana
c = apple
d = lemon
```

Check the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) for `ksort()`

Comment: Ksort just sorts the array by key, I was hoping for a function that can resort a 2nd array to match the first array.

Comment: how about using ksort() function to both arrays ? ?

Comment: using ksort() on both arrays will change order of both array, the question was to align the order of the 2nd array to the first one