# Sort multiple according to the keys of first array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 different arrays with same keys but different values

```
Array 1
(
[product_category_39] => Living Room
[product_category_40] => Dining Room
[product_category_38] => Bedroom
[product_category_44] => Kids Room
[product_category_43] => Home Office
[product_category_42] => Decor
[product_category_11] => Furnishings
[product_category_41] => Kitchen & Table Top
[product_category_45] => Bath
)

Array 2
(
[product_category_40] => std Object()
[product_category_39] => std Object()
[product_category_45] => std Object()
[product_category_38] => std Object()
[product_category_11] => std Object()
[product_category_42] => std Object()
[product_category_41] => std Object()
[product_category_43] => std Object()
[product_category_44] => std Object()
)

Array 3
(
[product_category_44] => val6
[product_category_39] => xyz
[product_category_42] => data5
[product_category_41] => pqr
[product_category_45] => val2
[product_category_11] => lmn
[product_category_38] => data12
[product_category_43] => abc
[product_category_40] => val 1
)
```

I want to sort these 3 arrays according to the keys of my first array. The keys should be in the same order as in the first array. what is the possible way to do this.

After sorting it should look like

```
Array 1
(
[product_category_39] => Living Room
[product_category_40] => Dining Room
[product_category_38] => Bedroom
[product_category_44] => Kids Room
[product_category_43] => Home Office
[product_category_42] => Decor
[product_category_11] => Furnishings
[product_category_41] => Kitchen & Table Top
[product_category_45] => Bath
) 


Array 2
(
[product_category_39] => std Object()
[product_category_40] => std Object()
[product_category_38] => std Object()
[product_category_44] => std Object()
[product_category_43] => std Object()
[product_category_42] => std Object()
[product_category_11] => std Object()
[product_category_41] => std Object()
[product_category_45] => std Object()
)

Array 3
(
[product_category_39] => xyz
[product_category_40] => val 1
[product_category_38] => data12
[product_category_44] => val6
[product_category_43] => abc
[product_category_42] => data5
[product_category_11] => lmn
[product_category_41] => pqr
[product_category_45] => val2
)
```

Comment: did you try anything? we can begin from there to help you out.

Comment: I am not much aware about this. I tried ksort(),asort() but my keys are changing. Then I tried array_multisort(array1,array2) but this also didn't work as expected.

Comment: When I need this kind of things, I *always find an example* of sorting **searching [so] archives**. Simple, complex, multidimensional, you name it... really, search and you'll find a solution already posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr1 = array(
    'b'=>1,
    'a'=>2,
    'c'=>3
);

$arr2 = array(
    'a'=>4,
    'b'=>5,
    'c'=>6
);

function sort_by_set($arr1,$arr2){
    foreach($arr1 as $key=>$value){
        $arr_new[$key] = $arr2[$key];
    }
    return $arr_new;
}

$arr2_new = sort_by_set($arr1,$arr2);
print_r($arr2_new);
```

it's a rebuilding,may be not a sorting

Comment: i agree. this is rebuilding; but nothing came to be me too other than this. good and easy.

Comment: Thanks. it worked. but it is increasing a loop though.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use this trick:

```
$first = array(
    'one' => 1,
    'three' => 3,
    'two' => 2,
);
$second = array(
    'two' => 'two',
    'one' => 'one',
    'three' => 'three'
);
uksort($second, function ($a, $b) use ($first) {
    foreach ($first as $key => $v) {
        if ($a == $key) {
            if ($b == $key) {
                return 0;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        if ($b == $key)
            return 1;
    }
    return 1;
});
var_dump($second);
```

In your case, with several arrays, you can take away callback function and use `$first` as `global`.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following link: [Sort array using another array keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338719/php-sort-an-array-by-key-to-match-another-arrays-order-by-key)

It answers your question or at least will give you a start on how to approach it. Good luck!

```
$arr1 = array(
    'a' => '42', 
    'b' => '551',
    'c' => '512',
    'd' => 'gge',
) ;


$arr2 = array(
    'd' => 'ordered',
    'b' => 'is',
    'c' => 'now',
    'a' => 'this', 
) ;

$arr2ordered = array() ;

foreach (array_keys($arr1) as $key) {
    $arr2ordered[$key] = $arr2[$key] ;
}
```