# Rearrange multidimensional array from other array

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, associative-array

```
$options = array(
array( "title" => "L", "value" => "L"),
array( "title" => "XL", "value" => "XL"),
array( "title" => "S", "value" => "S"),
array( "title" => "M", "value" => "M"),);


$options2 = array(
array( "title" => "S", "value" => "S"),
array( "title" => "M", "value" => "M"),
array( "title" => "L", "value" => "L"),
array( "title" => "XL", "value" => "XL"),);

the final data should be look like: 
$options3 = array('S','M','L','XL');
```

I want to re-arrange the $options sort by $options2 value;

the case is look like [php - sort an array by key to match another array's order by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338719/php-sort-an-array-by-key-to-match-another-arrays-order-by-key)

Comment: Have you tried something and what would be the expected output?

Comment: @Rizier123 the result should be same as $options2

Comment: If you already have `$options2` why can't you just use this array?

Comment: @Rizier123 $options is generated by system, and I cannot edit output from the system.. bu I have standard data by $options2, so I need rearrange $options look like $options2;

Comment: is it generated from database?

Comment: Can you give us an expected output of what you want it to look like? I'm confused at what you're saying by "sort by" $options2 value. All the titles are the exact same as the value.

Comment: @fsacer $options is generated from database;

Comment: @FrankerZ `$options2` to represent the result from sort.

Comment: @FrankerZ it same value, but different sort/arrangement

Comment: @andesign then show us the sql query and table structure

Comment: @andesign Your question is unclear to me. You say you can't change what is coming from `$options`, but you have `$options2` and now you want to sort `$options` by `$options2` value. And the expected result at the end should then be the same as `$options2`. So you do you even need `$options` ?!

Comment: I'm still rather confused here. You're only giving us 4 possible values. I can create you a sort function to sort through 4 options to get `$option2` expected output, but that would only work for `S`, `M`, `L`, and `XL` keys.

Comment: Your last edit, literally made this entire thing so much more confusing. Please think of this like we don't know the problem you're encountering. Give us more sample data, and give us expected output, not just "I want `$options3`.

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338719/php-sort-an-array-by-key-to-match-another-arrays-order-by-key

Comment: @andesign If $options is generated from database then you should have a way to affect output by ordering it by primary key which is probably not visible here.

Answer (score 0):

Both arrays have an arbitrary order. You want to re-arrange the first array to have the same order as the second array, correct ?

Alogrithm: iterate over the second array (and keep track of the current position), and for each item, you search for the equivalent item in the first array (from the current position forward) and then swap it into the current position.

Pseudo code:

```
for (curr_pos=0; curr_pos<options2.length; curr_pos++)
  for (pos=curr_pos; pos<options.length; pos++)
    if options2[curr_pos]==options[pos]:
      swap options[curr_pos], options[pos]
      break
```

If you can use extra space, then it would be more efficient using a hash map:

```
h=new HashMap()
for (pos=0; pos<options.length; pos++)
  h[options[pos].key]=options[pos].val
for (pos=0; pos<options2.length; pos++)
  options3[pos]= make_pair(options2[pos].key, h[options2[pos].key])
```

Comment: p.s. this can also be done quicker by putting the items of the first array into a hash table, and using that to find their position.  This would make the algorithm O(N) time and O(N) space, instead of O(N^2) time, O(1) space as shown above.

Comment: yes I want to arrange the first array same order as the second

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using array_shift php function.

Please use custom function rearrange_array.

```html
function rearrange_array($array, $key) {
  while ($key > 0) {
   $temp = array_shift($array);
   $array[] = $temp;
   $key--;
  }
  return $array;
 }
 
 
 $finalArray = rearrange_array($options,2);
```