# Array to DB::insert()->values(), which is in different order with the columns

Tags: php, arrays, model-view-controller, query-builder, kohana

*Hi folks!* I'm trying to transfer data as array from the **controller** to the **model**, and then paste the data into the **query builder**, but the data must be in the same order as specified in the columns.

- What options do I have?
- And do you think this is a bad practice?

**Controller:**

```
            $responseNotes = Model::factory('Notes')-> createTicket([
                'description'   => htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']),
                'contact_id'    => $_POST['contact_id'],
                'pref_contact'  => $_POST['pref_contact'],
                'dog_id'        => $_POST['document_id'],
                'type'          => $_POST['type'],
                'owner_id'      => Auth::instance()->get_user()->id,
                'cc'            => $_POST['cc-emails'],
                'title'         => $_POST['title']
            ]);
```

**Model:**

```
public function createNote(array $data)
{
    $columns = [
        'type',
        'owner_id',
        'cc',
        'title',
        'description',
        'contact_id',
        'pref_contact',
        'dog_id'
    ];
    if (!array_diff($columns, array_keys($data))) {
        // All needed values exists
        $result = DB::insert($this->NOTES, $columns)-> values($data)-> execute($this->SCHEMA);
    }
    return  ($result) ? $result : false ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12338779/5193609). Solved this by:

```
// Order $data array according to $column.values
$orderedData = [];
foreach ($columns as $key) {
    $orderedData[$key] = $data[$key];
}
$result = DB::insert($this->TICKETS, $columns)
    -> values($orderedData)
    -> execute($this->SCHEMA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `ORM Model`?

in controller:

```
$responseNotes = ORM::factory('Notes')-> values([
                'description'   => htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']),
                'contact_id'    => $_POST['contact_id'],
                'pref_contact'  => $_POST['pref_contact'],
                'dog_id'        => $_POST['document_id'],
                'type'          => $_POST['type'],
                'owner_id'      => Auth::instance()->get_user()->id,
                'cc'            => $_POST['cc-emails'],
                'title'         => $_POST['title']
            ])
try{
   $responseNotes->save();
} catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $ex) { 
   print_r($ex->errors('models'));
}
```

And don't use `htmlspecialchars($_POST['description'])`

In model class modify function ([doc](https://docs.koseven.ga/guide/orm/examples/validation)):

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
      'description' => array( array('htmlspecialchars') ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like You have associative array with structure db_column=>value right? Than You can simply insert like this:

```
DB::Insert('table_name',array_keys($data))->values(array_values($data))->execute();
```